# How to Update Edmx file using Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, edmx

I've created a Db and created a .edmx file, using Database first approach. In development, I've used "Update model from Database", if any new field added/ size modified. How can i update the model using code like in production environment.

Any Code alternative for updating model, when database changes.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In database first approach, you want to create a separate database project *(so that the changes won't affect the other projects)*.

Once database is changed, you just use 'Update model from Database' as you stated.

Then compile the application and copy the database project **dll** file to production.

Basically, you are just replacing the old **dll** file with new one.

**Note:** if your database and web application are in a same project, you'll need to copy the entire **dll** file.